# windows update broke bat file (I think)

Tags: batch-file

I believe a windows update broke my .bat file.
What this .bat file is supposed to do is update files within the folder with a date and time using nircmd.exe.
All file names start with mmddyy for reference.
Here is the .bat file code.

```
REM @echo on
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\optimize %%F in (*.*) DO call :Setfiletime %%F
goto End
:Setfiletime
   SET FNAME=%~n1
   echo %FNAME%
   SET MM=%FNAME:~0,2%
   SET DD=%FNAME:~2,2%
   SET YY=%FNAME:~4,2%
   nircmd.exe setfiletime %1 "%DD%-%MM%-20%YY% 18:00:00" "%DD%-%MM%-20%YY%18:00:00"
:goto :eof
:End
 REM endlocal
```

The output now shows each line before :Setfiletime, then ends with REM.
Why is this batch file no longer working and what would I need to do to fix it?

EDIT:  Fixed - file was in the wrong location.  The simplest solution was the best answer.

Comment: there *are* files in `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\optimize`, right?

Comment: Ha.  Well that was simple.  The file was moved.  This comment was the equivalent of "is it plugged in?" and sometimes it is not plugged in.

Comment: Voting to close the question as off-topic as it is not possible to recreate the problem.